# How to Stop Header from Overlapping with Navigation?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a fixed horizontal header that spans across the top, with a fixed vertical navigation bar on the left side. There is a area on the bottom right of the page with the "content" for the page. I have the header taking up 20% of the height of the page. I'm trying to figure out how to size/position the content and navigation elements so that they don't overlap with each other. As of right now, the navigation bar overlaps the header. When I set there to be a 20% margin at the top of both of these elements, they leave a large blank space in between them and the header.

[Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLW3K.jpg)

My Code:

```css
#header {
    background-color: #3265C9;
    position: fixed;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;   
}

#navigation {
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20%;
}

.navButton
{
    display: block;
    
}

#content {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    
}

body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>PriceCo</title>
    <link id="cssFile" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleA.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>

    <div id="header">
      <div>
        <img id="pricecoLogo" src="./img/cart.png" alt="logo" >
        <h1>PriceCo</h1>
      </div>
      <div>This is a store.</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="navigation">
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Departments</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Shop</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Cart</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Account</a>
    </div>
      
    <div id="content">
    CONTENT
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a final solution for you I'm sure but I think it answers your question.

- remove `position: fixed;` from header and nav
- remove `margin-top` from nav.

```css
#header {
  background-color: #3265C9;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#navigation {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navButton {
  display: block;
}

#content {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>PriceCo</title>
  <link id="cssFile" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleA.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <div>
      <img id="pricecoLogo" src="./img/cart.png" alt="logo">
      <h1>PriceCo</h1>
    </div>
    <div>This is a store.</div>
  </div>

  <div id="navigation">
    <a class="navButton" href="#">Departments</a>
    <a class="navButton" href="#">Shop</a>
    <a class="navButton" href="#">Cart</a>
    <a class="navButton" href="#">Account</a>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    CONTENT
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `top` instead of `margin-top`

```css
#header {
            background-color: #3265C9;
            position: fixed;
            height: 20%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-y: hidden;   
        }

        #navigation {
            background: yellow;
            position: fixed;
            height: 80%;
            width: 20%;
            top: 20%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .navButton
        {
            display: block;
            
        }

        #content {
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            margin-left: 20%;
            top: 20%;
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        body
        {
            margin: 0px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="header">
      <div>
        <img id="pricecoLogo" src="./img/cart.png" alt="logo" >
        <h1>PriceCo</h1>
      </div>
      <div>This is a store.</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="navigation">
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Departments</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Shop</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Cart</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Account</a>
    </div>
      
    <div id="content">
    CONTENT
    </div>
```